# type or namespace name 'Reset' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request.  Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately. Generated Code One
>   or more compilation references may be missing.
>
> If you're seeing this in a published application, set
>   'CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory' to true in your project file to
>   ensure files in the refs directory are published.
>
> The type or namespace name 'Reset' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?) public class
>   Views_Security_ResetPassword :
>   global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage The type or
>   namespace name 'Reset' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?) public
>   global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper Html {
>   get; private set; }

In local it's works fine: no errors, but in published server throws this error.

I'm using .net core 3.1

This happend when call \Security\ResetPassword Controller, and only in this, all other Controllers works without errors.

Obviously I did this: "set 'CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory' to true" but it's does not works.

My code is very simple:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RindeGastos.Infrastructure;
using RindeGastos.Models;
using RindeGastos.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;


namespace RindeGastos.Controllers
{


    public class SecurityController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext db = null;

        private readonly UserManager<AppIdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<AppIdentityRole> roleManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppIdentityUser> signinManager;

        public SecurityController(
        UserManager<AppIdentityUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<AppIdentityRole> roleManager,
        SignInManager<AppIdentityUser> signinManager,
        AppDbContext db)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
            this.signinManager = signinManager;
            this.db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult ResetPassword( string userId, string code)
        {
            Reset model = new Reset { UserId = userId, Code = code };

            return View(model);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(Reset model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await signinManager.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var code = WebUtility.UrlDecode(model.Code).Replace(" ","+");
                    IdentityResult result = userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, code, model.Password).Result;


                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("SignIn","Security");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Contraseña no pudo ser cambiada");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(model);

        }


    }
}

namespace RindeGastos.Models
{
    public class Reset
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Contraseñas no coinciden")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirme contraseña")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }

    public class Register
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Contraseñas no coinciden")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirme contraseña")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre completo")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of the whole Reset class please.

Comment: Please confirm that the file where Reset is located is published to the server together, please refer to this: https://forums.asp.net/t/1487100.aspx

Comment: I put class Reset in Question. It's in file Models/Register.cs in project

Comment: Another data: 'public class Views_Security_ResetPassword : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<Reset>' is in ResetPassword.cshtml.g.cs file. I don't know what this file is.

Answer (score -1):

I found it!.
I had published Views/ResetPassword.cshtml.
I deleted this files and it's working fine.

Regards